# DOJO without internet connection

Tags: dojo, offline

I require to build an intranet site using DOJO. The user should be able to use the site even without internet connection. But when I use `dojo.require("dojox.widget.AutoRotator");` it is fetching the JS files from `ajax.googleapis.com`.  Is there any way to avoid this. I specified a local location for dojo.js: 
`<script type="text/javascript" src="/dojo/dojo.js">`, but `AutoRotator.js` is not getting fetched from this location. It is fetching from internet.

Answer (score 3):

If you use a CDN hosted version of Dojo, then when you dojo.require anything, it pulls it.

If you want to avoid this, then you should create a build, or host your own version of Dojo locally.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. We have to give local path in "registerModule" of dojo.xd.js. Then JS will get picked up from the location which we give in registerModule.

Eg:

```
dojo.registerModulePath("dojo","/portal_dojo/dojo");

dojo.registerModulePath("dijit","/portal_dojo/dijit");

dojo.registerModulePath("dojox","/portal_dojo/dojox");
```